# Why is SystemDialogInput failing to return a save file path?

Tags: front-end

I am encountering a problem using `SystemDialogInput` within a `Button`. The
code below shows what I am doing. To test this create a couple of files
"myfile.txt" and "myfile2.txt" etc.

```
DynamicModule[{path = $HomeDirectory},

 Column[{
  Button["Save",
   path = SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "myfile.txt"];
   Print[FullForm@path],
   BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 11, Bold},
   ImageSize -> 120],
  Dynamic[path]
  }]
 ]
```

**1:** Press the "Save" button.

**2a:** Find e.g. "myfile.txt" and click on it;

or (next try)

**2b:** Type "myfile.txt" in the input field.

**3:** I then get the warning message asking me if I want to replace. I choose "Replace".

The problem is that the pathway 1->2a->3 seems to work ok, however 1->2b->3 seems to abort (no path returned). In other words when you type the file name of an exisitng file into the input field and try to save nothing happens.

I am using Mma 8.0.4 on OS X 10.6.8. WRI tech support say they cannot reproduce this.

**Q1.** Can anyone else reproduce this?

**Q2.** Can anyone suggest possible causes?

For those who post that it works for them can you give your system and version details. Thanks

**Edit**

I must be in need of a break because it does seem that the evaluation timeout is the cause so `Method -> "Queued"` is needed. Rookie mistake!

Not sure now whether this question even needs to be here. Probably not.

Comment: It works well for me

Comment: I see the same behaviour. What was throwing me initially was when I type the name and press 'Save' in the next attempt to save a file, without typing it, the path will not be updated either. Only after the second try I get an updated path.

Comment: @Mike please don't delete. Aside from the fact that it will bump the question #2000, this is the sort of thing other people might encounter. It might be a "rookie mistake" but there are plenty of rookies out there, especially around the interactive interface capabilities in Mathematica.

Comment: Mike, this question looks OK to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess it provides a lesson in looking for the obvious! Not sure what happened with this: The bug was clearly in my brain cells rather than the function. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the button option `Method -> "Queued"` to avoid evaluation timeout. Try this code:

```
DynamicModule[{path = $HomeDirectory}, 
 Column[{Button["Save", 
    path = SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "myfile.txt"];
    Print[FullForm@path], Method -> "Queued", 
    BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 11, Bold}, ImageSize -> 120], 
   Dynamic[path]}]]
```

Comment: While for some people/tests an evaluation timeout is a possibility, in this case it is not the cause of the problem. For example if I type *new* file name no such problem exists. The problem is only for existing file names.

Comment: Sorry for being unhelpful Mike, it didn't work for me, same behaviour as you described including that it worked with new file names, but now it works every time.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I too thought that this would be the problem. I can reproduce the problem and Method -> "Queued" really makes it go away.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: if you see that it sometimes works even without `Method->"Queued"` that's no surprise: it will depend on how fast you are, if you click "OK" within the timeout limit, I would expect the code to work even without the `Method` option, if you are too slow I would expect it to not work. Can you exclude that that was the reason why it worked for one case but not the other? I absolutely agree that `Method->"Queued"` should solve your problem, it has always solved exactly the same kind of problems for me...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes it goes away. I am going crazy?? :)